# Issues with Angular 2 promise passing object

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular-promise

I am having issues using a promise to return a Degree object in Angular 2.  The first return statement (uncommented) in **degree.service** works just fine in combination with the uncommented implementation of getDegree() in **build.component**.  However, when I try to switch to either of the commented implementations using a promise, the object always comes back as "undefined"

**degree.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Degree } from '../components/degree';
import { Category } from '../components/category';
import { Course } from '../components/course';

import { SAMPLE } from '../components/mock-degree';

@Injectable()
export class DegreeService{
  getDegree(){
    return SAMPLE;
    // return Promise.resolve(SAMPLE);
    // return new Promise<Degree>(function (resolve, reject) {
    //  resolve(SAMPLE);
    // })
  }
}
```

**build.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SEMANTIC_COMPONENTS, SEMANTIC_DIRECTIVES } from "ng-semantic";

import { Course } from '../course';
import { Category } from '../category';
import { PaneComponent } from './pane/pane.component';
import { Degree } from '../degree';

import { DegreeService } from '../../services/degree.service';


const blank: Category = {
  name: '',
  rank: 1,
  rulestat: 'no',
  categories: [],
  courses: []
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-build',
    directives: [SEMANTIC_COMPONENTS, SEMANTIC_DIRECTIVES, PaneComponent],
    templateUrl: `app/components/build/build.component.html`,
    providers: [DegreeService]
})



export class BuildComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private degreeService: DegreeService){}

  level: number = 1;
  currDeg: Degree;
  parents = [blank, blank, blank, blank];


  setLast(lst: Category){   //pass category objects, do all UI changing here
    this.level = lst.rank + 1;
    this.parents[lst.rank - 1] = lst;
  }

  getDegree(){
    //this.degreeService.getDegree().then(deg => this.currDeg = deg)
    this.currDeg = this.degreeService.getDegree();
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getDegree();
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does "*the object always comes back as "undefined"*" mean? When do you access it (too late)? Are you missing a scope application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you use the `currDeg` in your template but with promises, things are asynchronous. So the corresponding object will be undefined at the beginning since it will be set later (when the promise is resolved). And this, even if the promise is directly resolved with `Promise.resolve`.

```
export class DegreeService{
  getDegree(){
    return Promise.resolve(SAMPLE);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [DegreeService],
  templateUrl: 'src/app.html'
})
export class App {
  constructor(private degreeService:DegreeService) {
  }

  getDegree(){
    this.degreeService.getDegree().then(deg => {
      this.currDeg = deg;
      console.log('this.currDeg = ' + this.currDeg); // <------
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getDegree();
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/1fxE0okyMNj2JktURY4w?p=preview.

Comment: Thank you! You were right that it was a template issue. Even when directly resolved with a local degree object, the template tried to access currDeg too soon and there was nothing there.  Problem solved by initializing currDeg to a blank degree object.